# How to add metadata to the document using marklogic mapreduce connector api

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, marklogic

I wanted to write the document to marklogic database using marklogic mapreduce api, lets say here is the [example](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump/blob/master/mapreduce/src/main/java/com/marklogic/mapreduce/examples/HelloWorld.java). I wanted to add metadata to the document which i am writing it back to the marklogic database in the reducer -

```
context.write(outputURI, result);
```

If adding metadata to the document with mapreduce api of marklogic is possible please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used property **mapreduce.marklogic.output.content.collection** with the configuration xml. Adding this property added inserted data to that collection.

Answer (score 1):

For Metadata, I am assuming you are talking about the document properties fragment.  For background on document properties, please see here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/properties#id_19516

For use in MarkLogic mapreduce, please see here (the output classes): 
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mapreduce/output#id_76625

I believe you need to extend/modify your example to also write content to the properties fragment using the PropertyOutputFormat class.

One of the sample applications in the same documentation is an example of saving content in the properties fragment. If, however, you would like to fast-track yourself by looking at some source code: see some examples  - including writing to a document property fragment, see here: https://gist.github.com/evanlenz/2484318 - specifically LinkCountInProperty.java

Comment: I want to write document, at the same time have to put that into collection. When i am using setting OutputFormatClass to PropertyOutputFormat then it is searching for the documentURI  for which to add the property and if it is not able to find the documentUri then data is not inserting. When i am setting OutputFormatClass to ContentOutputFormat then the data is getting added as a document but did not have the property. I want to add the data as well as need to put the properties/metadata information as well. Please point to such example if there is any.